# R delete value from column if it does not contain itself in value from another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in `R` that looks like this:

| genus | species |
| --- | --- |
| Vulgatibacter | Vulgatibacter sp. |
| NA | Planctomyces |
| Holophaga | Geothrix sp. |

And I want to delete values from column species if the value from genus does not contain in species. I want to have this:

| genus | species |
| --- | --- |
| Vulgatibacter | Vulgatibacter sp. |
| NA | Planctomyces |
| Holophaga | NA |

`transform(.,Species= ifelse(Genus %in% Species, Species, NA))`  does not work.

Comment: Why should *Planctomyces* be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df |>
  mutate(species = case_when(mapply(grepl, sprintf("^%s", genus), species) ~ species,
                             is.na(genus) ~ species,
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   genus         species          
#>   <chr>         <chr>            
#> 1 Vulgatibacter Vulgatibacter sp.
#> 2 NA            Planctomyces     
#> 3 Holophaga     NA
```